# synching two computers connected with uart

Tags: serial-port, deadlock, uart

I have two different PCs that are connected serially and run different programs, both using UART 16650
The situation is:

Computer a sends data to b
Computer b receives from a
Computer b process data then respond to a
Computer a receives from b
A process data then respond to b
B receives...

And so on.

The problem is, a is too fast in processing while b is too slow such that a deadlock like situation occurs,I.e. at some instance,both pcs wait the other to send data

I need help how I can synch the PCs such that a PCs will not start to read data when the other is still reading

Comment: First thing, did you write both programs?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this problem is to designate one machine as the master, and the other as a slave.

master device: requests/polls data from slave, sends data to slave asking it to process

slave device: receives data, processes, and sends response back to master when polled

It would also be useful to add commands/queries from master to slave. This way you can check if the slave has data for you, and avoid waiting when it doesn't.

You're assuming that the deadlock is the result of differences between machine speeds, but have given no information that would prove that. In general, serial communication protocols should be able to recover from these kinds of situations.